# Setting up structs in C - giving strange errors

Tags: c

I have set-up structs like so in a C program:

```
typedef struct header block_header;

struct header {
    size_t size;
    block_header *next_pointer;
    block_header *prev_pointer;
};
```

However, when I run any expression like the following:

```
int myinit()
{
    block_header *p = init_heap_segment(BLOCK_HEAD_SIZE);

// etc etc
}
```

It gives me several errors for each function that it is declared in:

```
allocator.c: In function ‘myinit’:
allocator.c:37:38: error: ‘header’ undeclared (first use in this function)
allocator.c:37:38: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
allocator.c: In function ‘function’:
allocator.c:67:2: error: unknown type name ‘header’
```

What is the problem with the way that it is set-up? How do I make these errors go away?

EDIT: Definition of:

```
#define BLOCK_HEAD_SIZE (ALIGN(sizeof(header)))
```

Comment: The error message does not match the code you posted. You need to post the relevant code. The line from `myinit` that you quoted cannot produce such error messages by itself, unless the error is hidden by `BLOCK_HEAD_SIZE`. What's `BLOCK_HEAD_SIZE`? A macro?

Comment: 1) Show definition of `BLOCK_HEAD_SIZE` and `init_heap_segment()`.  2) Suspect typo in comment.

Comment: @chux I have edited it now. The code for the other function is provided, and we have to assume that there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your problem

```
#define BLOCK_HEAD_SIZE (ALIGN(sizeof(header)))
```

There's no such type as `header` in your program, which is what the compiler is telling you. You have defined type `struct header` and you have defined a typedef name `block_header` for it. So choose whichever you prefer: either `sizeof(struct header)` or `sizeof(block_header)`. But not `sizeof(header)`.

In C++ language defining a `struct header` type would also introduce typename `header` into the program. But not in C. In C the type defined by `struct header` is called `struct header` - two words. It cannot be shortened to a mere `header`.

Comment: Thank you! Will accept the answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In your program, there is no such type called `header`. But you are using

```
#define BLOCK_HEAD_SIZE (ALIGN(sizeof(header))) // problem
```

It should be-

```
#define BLOCK_HEAD_SIZE (ALIGN(sizeof(struct header)))
```

or

```
#define BLOCK_HEAD_SIZE (ALIGN(sizeof(block_header)))
```

Whenever you are calculating size like this, make sure that you are using correct parameters!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
typedef struct block_header {
    size_t size;
    block_header *next_pointer;
    block_header *prev_pointer;
}header;
```

and with that you can do:

```
header *p = init_heap_segment(BLOCK_HEAD_SIZE);
```

with a new declaration for init_heap_segment() where it returns 'header *' instead of 'struct block_header *'. Just much cleaner.

Comment: not the issue bro...though this does look better it is not causing the error.

Comment: No problem. At least with the error gone the real issue can be addressed. :)